# Перенаправление трафика из локальной сети на виртуальную машину

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, администрирование, virtualbox, iptables

**Дано:** сервер на Debian, на нем в VirtualBox крутится Ubuntu Server с nginx и парой сайтов. Сервер попутно является файловым хранилищем и интернет-шлюзом. 
**eth0** - внешняя сеть; 
**eth1** - внутренняя сеть.
**Извне доступ к сайтам есть.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема:** Есть локальная сеть 192.168.2.0 - из неё сайты **не доступны** с самого сервера тоже. Почему такое происходит, как это исправить? *Какие-то параметры могут показаться излишними - всё перепробовал от безнадежности.*
Решить вводом в локальную сеть 192.168.2.0 можно, но задача состоит именно в том, чтобы изолировать виртуалку от внутренней сети.

**Настройка сети VM - NAT с проброской портов:**
[image: Настройки проброса портов машины]

**iptables:**

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT ! -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK ACK -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED -j ACCEPT
...
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50080 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2102:690025]
:INPUT ACCEPT [761:114607]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1339:575308]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [737:112993]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2076:688301]
COMMIT
*nat
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 50080     
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

Comment: А чё не сетевой мост? Почему нат?

Comment: @don Rumata Чтобы виртуалка была заперта в своей сети и с неё доступа наружу не было.

Comment: Аа, тогда понятно.

Comment: Так за это же вроде DMZ как раз отвечает. Я же ничего не путаю? Если так, то гугли как её конфигруить. Типа https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD/ru

Comment: @donRumata так DMZ это же просто термин. Я как раз подобное и пытался реализовать. Но спасибо за наводку, почитаю, может получится выкинуть виртуалку наружу.

Comment: А зачем `-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE` маскарадить пакеты из интернета в локальную сеть ? это по идее должно приводить  к невозможности работы из этой локалки в интернете

Comment: @Mike Как я понимаю, для того чтобы при форварде определенных портов, внутренние узлы прозрачно работали с интернетом. Интернет из внутренней сети работает.

Comment: Я не вижу у вас ни одного форварда портов внутрь локальной сети. Только на другие порты самой машины. Да и если внутри доступен интернет и был бы форвард портов такой маскарад все равно был бы не нужен. Ведь он любой запрос из интернета на внутренние службы переделывает на обращение от имени самого сервера, что как минимум чревато тем, что отличить клиентов по ip будет невозможно. И кстати очень может быть, что именно из за этого правила у вас что то не работает. уберите его, если проблемы останутся тогда скажите какие сайты не доступны из локалки и по какому ip, с eth0 или eth1

Comment: @Mike форварды я вырезал, чтоб место не занимали. Убрал маскарад - не помогло, но ничего, вроде, и не сломалось. Обновил вопрос - добавил схему. Нет доступа из local network (eth1) на bormoshka.ru (lo?)

Comment: Ну если снаружи доступ есть, может это за счет `-A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 50080`  и если так, то тогда точно такое же правило для eth1 должно решить проблему

Comment: @Mike В таком случае весь трафик завернется на локальный сервер. Да, я и попробовал, интернет в локальной сети пропадает. Но локальный сайт, тем не менее, не открывается.

Comment: @bormoshka Это странно, что не заработало. А то что отрубился интернет, да, логично, не досмотрел, в правиле надо указать IP назначения (-d) на который изначально идет пакет (тот в который резолвится bormoshka.ru на внутренних машинах). Надеюсь вы проверяли не с сервера, а с машины изнутри ? с самого сервера что бы работало средствами iptables скорее всего не выйдет. Вообще я бы предложил на 80 порту хост-машины поднять nginx и настроить редирект через него

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил прислушаться к совету @Mike - поставить на хост nginx и делать прокси-редирект.

1. Установить nginx ([инструкция](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/installing-nginx-open-source/))
2. Удалить (закомментировать строчки) /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
3. Создать файл конфига, например:

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf

```
server {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:50080;
    }
}
```

4. service nginx restart
5. В настройках VirtualBox достаточно оставить проброс портов для адреса и порта хоста  127.0.0.1:50080 и порта гостевой ОС - 80
6. Чтобы пустить весь трафик через nginx:

> iptables

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT ! -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK ACK -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
#Черный список портов
#-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport xxxx:yyyy -j DROP
#Белый список портов
#-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport xxxx:yyyy -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 --dport 5689 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50020 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2102:690025]
:INPUT ACCEPT [761:114607]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1339:575308]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [737:112993]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2076:688301]
COMMIT
*nat
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
#список форвардов на локальную машину
#-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 --dport xxxx -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.2
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
#-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы видите какой-то ответ от веб-сервера если зайдете по адресу 10.0.2.15 то
проблема вся в том, что когда идет доступ из интернета к сайту, то (упрощенно)
клиент резолвит ip домена bormoshka.ru и получает адрес 1.1.1.1 (к примеру). Далее стучится на этот адрес и этот запрос перенаправляется на виртуалку. ибо есть форвард порта.

Но, если клиент стучится из внутренней сети, то он также зарезолвит ip 1.1.1.1 (внешний) и будет стучаться туда, все вроде верно, но получив такой запрос ваш маршрутизатор подставит в src ip локальный адрес (192.168.2.25 к примеру) и отправит его в виртуалку, web сервер сгенерирует ответ и пошлет его обратно по тому же маршруту, но на сей раз маршрутизатор отправит пакет в интернет, т.к. ему то вроде пришел пакет через eth1 в конченом итоге. Поэтому у вас есть два варианта либо поднять(настроить) DNS сервер на хосте виртуалок и прописать что-бы по запросу bormoshka.ru резолвилось 10.0.2.15. Либо создать loopback nat таким вот образом

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 10.0.2.15/32 -p tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
или
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.0.2.15 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source внешний_ip`

Расписано очень упрощенно.

Comment: Ответа от веб-сервера на 10.0.2.15 из локальной сети нет. Вчера ещё пробовал оба эти правила - не заработало. Пробую дальше...

Comment: Заметил такую особенность - раньше я думал что если перейти на bormoshka.ru:50080 с локальной сети, то это не приводит к успеху. Оказалось, что доступ по этому порту есть, просто nginx или wp осуществляют редирект на 80 порт (через telnet соединение установилось). Со статичными сайтами такого не происходит. Мне кажется где-то путаница с редиректами с 80 на 50080 порт.